# on the colon it's says "," is expected in vite + react from createBrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, vite

Hi I've been searching and can't find any similar problem I'm facing the server is running but it's doesn't work as expected from the tutorial I'm following

I'm using vs code my xampp, composer, Laravel, nodejs and npm are all latest version so here is the code

```
import {createBrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

//Specify the routes
const router = createBrowserRouter  (routes : [])
export default router;
```

the colon before the routes (routes :) have underline red and says "," is expected I'm following this video https://youtu.be/qJq9ZMB2Was around 23:02

Much appreciated for helping I'm still learning and a beginner from this field

There should be no underline red

Answer (score 1):

The `routes:` that you're seeing in the video isn't actually in the code; it is from an IDE extension that displays the names of function parameters for the developer. So just change it to:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([])
```